# Am I using TexStorage correctly or is this a driver bug?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to compress a texture to BPTC using this code but I am getting a corrupted image.

```
glTextureStorage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 10, GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, 512, 512);
glTextureSubImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_buffer);
```

On the other had, if I use this it works.

```
glTextureImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_buffer);
```

Also, if I do this:

```
glTextureStorage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 10, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 512, 512);
glTextureSubImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_buffer);
```

My texture appears overexposed, but if I do this:

```
glTextureImage2DEXT(texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_buffer);
```

It appears correctly.

For the record, glGetError and KHR_debug report no errors and nothing changes if I used the non-direct_state_access versions of these functions. Can somebody please tell me if I am using these functions incorrectly or if this is a driver bug.

EDIT: OK, so if this isn't already confusing enough. I decided to use glGetTexLevelParameteriv to actually check the internal format of the texture after creation. When I create the texture with glTexImage2D and GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, glGetTexLevelParameteriv comes back with a format of GL_SRGB_ALPHA. If I create the texture with glTexStorage2D and GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, glGetTexLevelParameteriv comes back with a format of GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, but of course if I use glTexSubImage2D on it, it ends up corrupted (colorful noise). I tried GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT. glTexImage2D seems to work fine. It says the texture is actually S3TC. glTexStorage2D is also able to handle it, without corrupting the image, but as with GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 the image comes out looking overexposed, as if it is being treated as linear data.

Comment: Why are you using the …EXT functions? Why not glTexStorage2D and glTexSubImage2D which are core functions.

Comment: @datenwolf Why are you asking me that? I already said that I tried the non-DSA versions with the same effect. To answer your question, I am using DSA because I am targeting desktop computers with graphics cards that all support EXT_direct_state_access which is an extremely useful extension.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a particular reason. Since it's an EXT extension there's no requirement for an OpenGL extension to actually implement it. Yet DSA would be nice to have in core.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem (you probably are not using a mipmapped `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`) but you are allocating storage for 10 mipmap levels, but only uploading data for the base level.  Anyway I haven't used `TextureStorage` with compressed or sRGB internal formats but it seems like you're using it properly, seems like it might be a driver bug to me; like it's just inserting the data you upload with `SubImage` verbatim, ignoring the format conversion?

Comment: If you use `glTexImage2D` with `null` data pointer instead of `glTexStorage2D`, does `glTexSubImage2D` still give incorrect results?

Comment: I'm using glGenerateMipmaps to fill in the rest of the mip levels. I've actually found another bug related to using glGenerateTextureMipmapEXT with glTexStorage2D or glTextureStorage2DEXT (found here http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1301599#1301599) so I would not be surprised at all if I was doing things correctly and it was the drivers fault.

Comment: I replaced glTexStorage2D with the equivalent pseudo-code found in the extension document (http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_storage.txt) and it works correctly.

Comment: OK, so if this isn't already confusing enough. I decided to use glGetTexLevelParameteriv to actually check the internal format of the texture after creation. When I create the texture with glTexImage2D and GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, glGetTexLevelParameteriv comes back with a format of GL_SRGB_ALPHA. If I create the texture with glTexStorage2D and GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, glGetTexLevelParameteriv comes back with a format of GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_BPTC_UNORM, but of course if I use glTexSubImage2D on it, it ends up corrupted (colorful noise).

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or is it just that AMD's drivers are completely broken. If it's the later, how is it that only I have ran into this?

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question or asking a new question rather than directing people to read the comments, but IMHO it looks like someone at AMD needs to find a new profession.  Is this with the latest catalyst drivers?  What hardware is it running on?  Is it also broken with COMPRESSED_*_S3TC formats?

Comment: I tried GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT. glTexImage2D seems to work fine. It says the texture is actually S3TC. glTexStorage2D is also able to handle it, without corrupting the image, but as with GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 the image comes out looking overexposed, as if it is being treated as linear data.

Comment: I have a HD 5850 and I'm using the latest drivers, the one with OpenGL 4.3 support.

Comment: What happens if you only supply 1 mipmap LOD when you allocate your texture storage with `TexStorage2D (...)`? I cannot help but think that the major difference between the two snippets of code is that `TexImage2D (...)` is mipmap incomplete since it only allocates storage for 1 out of the 1,000 mipmap LODs (yes, this sounds ridiculous but it is how GL works) that textures normally have. `TexStorage2D (...)` on the other hand, actually sets the value of `TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` when you call it and allocates storage for each of the quarter-res mipmap LODs which is one major difference.

Comment: I had mentioned in the comments that I implemented TexStorage2D myself in terms of TexImage2D using the psudocode from the spec. I am also filling in all mip levels using GenerateMipmap. This works fine.